# sequence of entries in the BREAK tag

Tags: hunspell

Does the sequence of entries in the BREAK tag matter?

For e.g. I have this affix file

```
BREAK 2
BREAK s
BREAK es
```

And there is only one word in the dictionary file.

```
die
```

And if I type "**dies**" will it be marked as incorrect? If I change the sequence as shown below will it mark dies as incorrect?

```
BREAK 2
BREAK es
BREAK s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of entries in the BREAK tag should not matter, with [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io/) (past [`BREAK 2`](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/blob/2d71200264234c2c59e3daa1a40576f794518564/man/hunspell.5#L347): "number_of_break_definitions").

The `BREAK` tag is used to define how words can be broken down into smaller parts for better spell checking.

In your example, the affix file specifies that words can be broken down using "`s`" or "`es`" as possible word parts.

If you have only one word "`die`" in your dictionary file and your affix file allows breaking with "`s`" and "`es`," then typing "`dies`" should not be marked as incorrect since "`die`" is in the dictionary and "`s`" is a valid word part as per the `BREAK` rules.

Changing the sequence of the `BREAK` entries should not affect the spell checking behavior because Hunspell will consider all the defined word parts when breaking down a word.
So, in both cases, "dies" should be considered correct.